# Importing CSV file into postgreSQL but have duplicates

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I am importing CSV data into postgreSQL using Python. I seem to have duplicates in my CSV file. I have five columns in my CSV file and one of them is username. How can I tell Python to show me the duplicates with the same username in my file. Please provide your kind assistance. I am new to Programming so please pardon my stupidity. If it's not possible with this code and script, how can I manipulate the code so I can find them duplicates in the CSV file.

```
import psycopg2
import csv

csv_data = csv.reader(file('SampleData2.csv'))
```

Comment: "I seem to have duplicates in my CSV file. " Why? Does PostgreSQL give you an error? Which error?

Comment: When I run a query in postgreSQL, count(username) > 1 it returns lots of usernames. A username is a unique field it shouldn't have duplicates. I want to see those duplicates in Python and then once I see them, I want to be able to delete them. I want to do this process in Python.

Comment: So you can [edit] your question and delete all the PostgreSQL related code your question is not about. Instead include the code you've tried to remove duplicates from the CSV input.

Comment: Thanks Lutz, I have edited the original post to reflect my concern.

Comment: Now please add a sample of the input that does contain duplicates. Please also explain *why* they are duplicates. Don't forget to include the Python code you have tried to detect and remove them.

Comment: @Pythonlearner, You have to use Sets in Python.https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: Thanks Developer, yes I have to use Sets but I don't know any code regarding sets in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to be able to import the file into the database without creating duplicates you can do an 'UPSERT' of sorts.  This will update (which won't matter since its a duplicate) or create a new record.

See this SO answer: [Insert, on duplicate update in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql#6527838)

Comment: Thanks Joshua, right now I just want to see the list of duplicates with the same username.